# How to execute a funtion on @Input parameter in angularjs2?

Tags: javascript, function, angular, input, parameters

I wanted to execute doClean() function on @Input() cleanTextBox

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'my-component',
      providers: [],
      template: `<input [(ngModel)]="abc">`,
      directives: []
    })
    export class Directive {
      @Input() cleanTextBox : boolean;
      public abc = "someValue";

     // Execute doClean function if cleanTextBox is true
       public doClean{
           this.abc = '';
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a setter

```
export class Directive {

  private _cleanTextBox: boolean;

  @Input() set cleanTextBox(value: boolean) {
    if (value) {
      this.doClean();
    }
    this._cleanTextBox = value;
  }

  get cleanTextBox() {
    return this._cleanTextBox;
  }

  public abc = "someValue";

  public doClean{
    this.abc = '';
  }
}
```